# check whether matrix has row that is permutation of another and keep only one of it

Tags: r, permutation, subset

I have the following problem:

I have an k*2 matrix with unique rows (unique() command was applied before), so the essential part is, it has two columns.

Now I only want to keep the rows which are not a permutation of another row,

but in such a way that if there is a permutation, I do want to keep one of the two!

background: each element of this matrix is associated w/ a column of another data vector and I wantt to take differences of many 2 such vectors, and project on the resulting (difference) vector. 
But projecting on +/- the vector is the same, so this is for this application a duplicate.

Example:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    2    1
```

Desired result:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a copy of the matrix
2. Sort each of its rows
3. Find the indices of non-duplicate rows using the `duplicated` function
4. Select these rows from the original matrix

or if the order does not matter, just run `unique` after step 2.